# Proof about Extension and Contraction of Ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, solution-verification

Let $f : A \longrightarrow B$ be a ring homomorphism. Let $I \subseteq A$  be an ideal of $A$ and $J \subseteq B$ be an ideal of $B$.  By definition, the *extension* of $I$ is:
    $$
 I^{e} = \{ \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i}f(x_{i}) : a_{i} \in B,\; x_{i} \in I,\; \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \}
 $$
    and the *contraction* of $J$ is $f^{-1}(J) = J^{c}$.

The following property holds: $(J^{c})^{e} \subseteq J$.

**My Proof**: Suppose $J \subsetneq (J^{c})^{e} $. Let $x \in J$. Then $f^{-1}(x) \in f^{-1}(J) = J^{c}$. Now, \begin{align*}
 (f^{-1}(J))^{e} = (J^{c})^{e} &= \{ \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i}f(f^{-1}(x_{i})) : a_{i} \in B,\; f^{-1}(x_{i}) \in J^{c},\; \forall n \in \mathbb{N}\}\\
 &=  \{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i}x_{i} : a_{i} \in B,\; x_{i} \in J,\; \forall n \in \mathbb{N}\}\\
 &= J,
 \end{align*}  contradiction to our assumption that $J \subsetneq (J^{c})^{e} $. Hence, $J \supseteq (J^{c})^{e}$.

Can somebody confirm either or not the proof is correct?

Comment: Okay, so you assume $J$ is a proper subset of $J^{ce}$ and arrive at $J=J^{ce}$(I didn't go through the details of your proof). Thus $J$ is not a proper subset of a $J^{ce}$. I don't understand how you conclude your proof. I would recommend writing a direct proof.

Comment: @ Thomsa Shelby. Like you wrote, I assume the opposite statement is true, that is $J$ is a proper subset of $J^{ce}$ and arrive at $J = J^{ce}$, which is a contradiction to the assumption. Then the original statement is true instead.

Comment: @ Thomsa Shelby. I already have a direct proof, but I want to have another way to prove it.

Comment: The negation of $A\subseteq B$ is $A\not\subseteq B$, i.e., there exists some $x\in A$ such that $x\notin B$. The subset relation is only a partial order.

Comment: @Thomas Shelby. What you wrote is similar to $x \in A \wedge x \notin B$. So in my case similar to: assume $x \in J \wedge x \notin J^{ce}$ and arrive at $J = J^{ce}$, which means that the strict inclusion is not possible. Hence, the other inclusion exists.